# How to specify dataset location using BigQuery API v0.27?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to figure out how to specify the dataset location in a BigQuery API query using v0.27 of the BigQuery API.

I have a dataset located in `northamerica-northeast1` and the BigQuery API is returning 404 errors since this is not the default multi-regional location "US."

I am using the `run_async_query` method to execute my queries but based on documentation am unsure how to add a location to this field to make it location aware.

I have also tried to previously update my client instantiation like this:

```
def _get_client(self):
  bigquery.Client.SCOPE = (
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
  client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(_KEY_FILE)
  if self._params['bq_data_location'].strip():
    client.location = self._params['bq_data_location']
  return client
```

However, it does not appear that this is the correct way to inform the BigQuery API of a dataset location.

For additional context, in my SQL that I am passing to the BigQuery API, I am already specifying the `PROJECT_ID.DATASET_ID.TABLE_ID`, however, this does not seem to be sufficient to find regional data.

Furthermore, I am making this request from Google App Engine using the [CRMint](https://github.com/google/crmint) open source data flow platform.

Can you please help me with an example of how location can be added to the BigQuery API for v0.27 so that the API does not return 404?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code sample it seems you're likely talking about google-cloud-bigquery 0.27, which was released in Aug 2017 and predates location support (as well as many other features).

Your best bet is to update that dependency to [something more recent](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/#history).

Comment: Yes, dataset location appears to have only been introduced in 0.32 at earliest. Upgrading kind of is the only solution here.